# Is there a way to embed coverage from SonarQube into a Github project as an icon?

Tags: github, sonarqube, markdown

Is it possible to embed code coverage results (stored in SonarQube) into Github projects as one of those embeddable icon gadgets (not sure what their name is; it would be great if somebody to tell me that as well)...? I'm referring to the ones that show the build status, for example.

Comment: Hi, I'm the developer of the plugin mentioned by @Ann. Currently the plugin only displays the quality gate status of a project analysed on a SQ instance. Providing other types of images will be possible, however some questions remain open (for instance what metrics, what background color, should the color be chosen based on the quality gate that applies to the project, etc.) If possible I would like to allow users to fully customise the image. If you have ideas, opinion, use cases, please create an issue on the plugin's page: https://github.com/QualInsight/qualinsight-plugins-sonarqube-status

Comment: @kraal: Thanks for your efforts in providing such a plugin! I think it should have three colours: green when the code coverage is greater, or equal to the defined threshold, yellow, when it's something like 5-10% below it and red when it's much lower than that. I think it should show something like "SonarQube: 84%" (or something along those lines). I have to admit, I still haven't had the time to test your plugin, but I'll definitely do so soon, as I'm quite interested in this. Once again, thanks for your hard work!

Comment: From a colors perspective this is what is planned, however from a treshold perspective, my opinion is that I should rely on the quality gate itself and avoid other computation (if no gate is defined, a gray background should be set then). Concerning the text to be displayed, it will be something like "UT Coverage | 80%". I also still have to find a way to cache correctly generated images in order to avoid DoS attacks. Your input / comments are really welcome ! Cheers.

Comment: I created a Google group in order to have a place where we can share ideas about this plugin and where you can describe your feature requests. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/svg-status

Comment: the plugin displays measures since version 2.0.0, next version (2.1.0) will colorise them (already implemented, you can clone the project, build and try it.) Side note: the project moved to https://github.com/QualInsight/qualinsight-plugins-sonarqube-badges

Comment: @Kraal, Thanks for the update! There's a limitation with the authentication that is still keeping us from being able to use this. What is the likelihood of this being fixed in upcoming releases?

Comment: As is, unfortunately close to none. They (SQ team) don't want to allow web services to be callable if user authentication is forced for security reasons. While I don't agree with them (security is a concern but admins should have the final word IMHO) I can't do anything on my side. I have ideas about how this limitation could be removed (a configuration screen or server property to explicitly allow or block web services requesting to be visible when auth is forced // or "signed" web services) but then it would be the community that would have to vote (massively) for this idea (or develop it))

Comment: I would really like to see this functionality implemented... Is there some ticket with SQ that you've opened for this? I can vote for it, if necessary... If you could think of a workaround and implement it, this would be absolutely fantastic! I've been following your project closely and the progress seems constant and great! Keep up the good work!

Comment: here is a workaround suggestion (I still have to implement it): http://serverfault.com/questions/815026/use-haproxy-to-add-credentials-under-the-hood

Comment: Apparently, this is a topic of quite some interest, as it has now been viewed more than 1000 times. Is there any progress on this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The only thing currently available is [this under-development plugin](https://github.com/QualInsight/qualinsight-plugins-sonarqube-status), which was first discussed in this [Google Group thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/sonarqube/build$20status/sonarqube/XvmfnLJ5vgk/WRDsoUw-BQAJ). Note that this project appears to be in its infancy.

**EDIT**

This plugin has since been released, and can be installed directly from the Update Center

**EDIT 2**

With SonarQube 7.1, badges become a native feature.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look and give it a try! :)

Comment: Is there any way we can move this along? The plugin which Kraal developed, has hit a limitation on your side and there's not much he can do to fix it, unless you guys make some changes. Are there any plans to look into this?

Comment: Not the place @carlspring. Try the [SonarQube Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?pli=1#!forum/sonarqube) instead.

Comment: Finally! I can't believe it took so long for this to become a native feature.

Comment: Wait a moment... So 3 years later Sonar has finally added badges as a native feature. However, the Sonar team still hasn't figured out how to allow badges for non-public projects! This is just hilarious! :D (https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/MMF-1178)

Answer (score 3):

Using a plugin in no longer needed, as some new APIs are now added that will do what you want. You can use this snippet in your `.md` files:

```
[![SonarCloud Coverage](https://{domain}/api/project_badges/measure?project={projectName}&metric=coverage)](https://{domain}/component_measures/metric/coverage/list?id={projectName})
```

Note that you have to replace parameters inside `{}`s with your own values. If you are using on-premise version, the `domain` will be your own domain and if you are using cloud version, it will be `sonarcloud.io`.

Also note that this will work only for public projects. For private ones, I could not find any solution.

And finally as a side note, the `metric` parameter takes some values other than `coverage` and gives other fantastic badges that you may find helpful:

```
bugs, code_smells, coverage, duplicated_lines_density, ncloc, sqale_rating, alert_status, reliability_rating, security_rating, sqale_index, vulnerabilities
```